# alternative to mysql_fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysql

I want to execute a query and either it will return one row or none. I don't want to use mysql_fetch_array(). What else can I do?

Comment: Why not use `mysql_fetch_array()`?

Comment: I was doubting that I need to use While unnecessarily. I wanted to get rid of the While loop.

Comment: Please try using the PEAR::MDB2 database abstraction library instead of calling the mysql function calls directly.

Comment: What are the advantages of it? Any link?

Comment: There are lots of alternatives to using the direct mysql calls. But what the hell?

Comment: Yes, there are two big advantages:
1. Built in SQL parametrization support which when used correctly eliminates SQL injection problems.
2. Allows you to easily switch database engines by changing the connection string.  (No need to replace all your mysql_fetch_array() calls with the equivalent postgresql/Oracle/MSSQL calls.)

There are plenty of other advantages as well.

http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2/

Comment: Or use PDO (http://php.net/PDO), which has the same advantages as the PEAR MDB2 abstraction. As for which one, they're getting more and more similar. Depends largely on what the host has available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatives to `mysql_fetch_array()`

1. [`mysql_fetch_object()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_object)
2. [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc)
3. [`mysql_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_row)

You don't have to use a while loop. Using `mysql_num_rows()` you can check the number of returned rows. This works on the resultset that is returned from a `mysql_query()` call.

```
$res = mysql_query('select 0');
if (mysql_num_rows($res)) {
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($res);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you've got only one (or zero) rows to pull.

```
$result = mysql_query(/* ... */);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
mysql_free_result($result);
```

If there is a row, `$row` will have it. If not - `$row` will be `false`. No need for `while()`.

---

If you just want to know how many rows you've got

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: I see. Ok, is there any way to determine the number of rows in an array? Anything like row_count.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a function to do it for you.

```
function get_one_row($query) {
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 return($row);
}
```

Or are you trying to eschew mysql_fetch_array entirely?